# How to integrate whatsapp share button into javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one code which currently bring all ipad visitors to website.com and all remaining visitors to website.net

Now I want to edit the code, and change the function assigned on ipad visitors from window.open url into "share website.com url through whatsapp" action.

Can you help me with the code?

```
<script>function Share()

{ if( /iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { window.open('http://website.com/'); }

else{ window.open('http://website.net/'); } } </script>

<div class="whatsapp_button"><img src="../images/whatsapp.png" onclick="Share()"></div>
```

I need to integrate the following code to replace from the above code `(window.open('http://website.com/');`)

with this one:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Please visit website.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"></a></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function Share(){
if( /iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    window.open('http://website.com');
}else{
document.write('<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=40753023777&text=Please visit Website.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" class="offer1"></a>'); 
} 
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @AdyDev looks like the code document.write isn't working, set up this way: please have a look https://jsbin.com/dimeficuzo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Still, it doesnt work. I'm pretty sure it's due to the recall <div class="MyClass"><img src="../images/whatsapp.png" onclick="Share()" draggable="false"></div> which is not working. While a common a href works. How can I edit a recall making it work calling the Share() function?

Comment: I will update href for you with my phone number and works fine. Please try and tell me. Thank you!